# Sorting data inside of IQueryable object

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I have problem with sorting data from IQueryable variable.

My code is not in English so I will mock up important code.

My `Order` class has instance of `OrderState` class, and my `OrderState` class has an instance of `State` class.

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual ICollection<OrderState> OrderState { get; set; }
}

public class OrderState
{
    public int OrderStateId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<State> State { get; set; }
}

public partial class State
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

In my API service class, I would like to create list which has all orders, but each order has only last created `OrderState` class instance.I know how to get all data but struggle with sorting `Orderstate` list property to get only relevant `OrderState`. I need to use `IQueryable` list.

Here is my API code:

```
var query = _context.Set<Database.Order>().AsQueryable();

if (search.UserId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.UserId == search.UserId);
}

if (search.OrderId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.OrderId == search.OrderId);
}

if (search.LoadCurrentOrderState)
{
    // I don't know how to sort by orderstate desc and take only first item
    query = query.Include("OrderState").Include("OrderState.State");
}

var entities = query.ToList();

return _mapper.Map<List<Model.Order>>(entities);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you using EF or EF Core? Specify the exact version.

Comment: EF Core v5.0.5 , .net core 3.1 @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lucky: in EF Core 5.0 the [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) feature has appeared.

```
query = query
    .Include(o => o.OrderState.OrderByDescending(os => os.OrderStateId).Take(1))
    .Include("OrderState.State");
```

Such a query should give the desired result.
`Take(1)` returns first item.